# Maintaining a videos aspect ratio in a responsive layout

Tags: html, css, video

I'm trying to maintain a videos aspect ratio in a responsive layout to prevent black edges when the layout changes size. So far, I've set up some media queries, but while re-sizing there are still some points that the video has black edges.

You can see the layout and video here http://smedia.lv/ (the SHOWREEL video).

The video is embedded from Vimeo with an iframe and it has a width and height of 100%. The video container width depends on the screen size and is also defined in %, the height is a fixed value.

How can I keep the aspect ratio of the video, so it doesn't have the black edges?

Comment: http://fitvidsjs.com/

Comment: This didn't work out as planned, it just made the video container square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [fluid width video](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php).

Adding just a few styles to your container (`.video`) and the `iframe` will accomplish this.

```
.video {
  height: 410px;
  width: 964.71px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* Adjust the max-width depending on the other styles on your site. */
@media(max-width: 1046px) {
  .video {
    position: relative;
    /* 40:17 aspect ratio */
    padding-bottom: 42.5%;
    height: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Checkout the example below.

Note:

- You can use a media query to setup a breakpoint at which point the video will grow no bigger than 964.71x410.
- You will need to update the `padding-bottom`, `.video width`, and *media query* to reflect the correct aspect ratio of your video if it changes.

```css
.video {
  height: 410px;
  width: 964.71px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media(max-width: 1046px) {
  .video {
    position: relative;
    /* 40:17 aspect ratio */
    padding-bottom: 42.5%;
    height: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/120261170" width="500" height="213" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution did not work either. It just expands the video trough out the whole page.

Comment: @TacoCat I've update the answer to include a media query.  This should help you in enforcing what I understand is a  `max-height` of `410px` requirement.